# Sending Integers to an Android Background App

Tags: c#, android, c++, xamarin.android

For a personal project, I want to be able to send an (x,y) coordinate to an Android phone (4.4.2), and then use the received data point to simulate a touch event.

The process looks as following:
| PC |  ===[Integer data]===> | Android | ===>[Simulate touch event]

I am currently using c++ on visual studios and Xamarin for Android app development (C#)

How can I approach the problems:
1) Communication (sending data) from PC to Android background task app
2) Simulating a touch event.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is via an IP socket between the two. Create a background Android service that's listening on this incoming socket.

Since you are local, you could also issue an ADB command to do a broadcast INTENT with the payload carrying what event you want to issue to a service that injects it into the system. You might also be able to leverage the uiautomater to induce the touch events, see http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html